# Google Sheets - Show text in cell based on 3 other cells - 1: Not blank, 2+3: Yes/No

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, nested-if

I'd like my output cell to show "Success" / "Not quite there" based on 3 cells:

1. Blank / not blank
2. Yes / No
3. Yes / No

My issue is with combining the "isblank" in the "IF".

The below formula is the closest I've gotten and it's not working -

```
=(if(and(E3<>,F3="Yes",G3="Yes"),"Success!","Not quite there"))
```

Would love your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF((E3="")*(F3="yes")*(G3="yes"); "Success!"; "Not quite there")
```

or:

```
=IF((E3<>"")*(F3="yes")*(G3="yes"); "Success!"; "Not quite there")
```

for array use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E3:E="")*(F3:F="yes")*(G3:G="yes"); "Success!"; "Not quite there"))
```

if you need OR logic replace `*` with `+`

example:

```
=IF((E3="")*((F3="yes")+(G3="yes")); "Success!"; "Not quite there")
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you very much!! The 2nd option is exactly what I was looking for :)